# jQM Knockout.js containerless control flow syntax

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, mobile-browser

I'm using jqm 2.3 and knockout 2.2.1. This is the code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: items() -->
...some code...
<!-- /ko -->
```

If I use Wi-Fi connection on my android smartphone, It's all ok.
Instead if I use mobile connection, return error on knockout binding where some internal elements at items are not defined.

Somebody help me?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: read is not defined;

Where "read" is a property of items, but if i connect wi-fi, every ok. In debug mode with mobile connection I can view that "read" has value 1, but knockout doesn't fire binding.

Comment: I've created an example from knockout web-site...

http://jsfiddle.net/uUX9f/

If this example is runned from a normal connection works fine. In you run this example from slow connection (mobile for ex.) doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is a problem of Android browsers that doesn't parse comment if connection slow.

I have rounded the problem whith a component knockout: [knockout-repeat.js](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat)

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li data-bind="repeat: { foreach: people, item: '$item' }" data-repeat-bind="text: $item().firstName">
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/uUX9f/3/

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a timing issue where either your DOM or your viewmodel hasn't been built before you apply your bindings; pretty much the only difference between a wifi and a mobile connection is going to be the speed and order of various components coming in.

Make sure that your script doesn't start running until the DOM is complete (either put it/the reference to it at the end of your `<body>` or put it in a jQuery DOM-ready handler), and that it doesn't call `applyBindings` before the viewmodel has built (make sure the call to `applyBindings` occurs at the end of the function that creates your VM).

Comment: I'm using: `$(document).on('pageshow', '#main-page', initialize);`

In initialize function I create the viewModel and at the end of that function I apply the binding:

`ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`

Comment: That's error present on Android smartphone with any browser (Chrome, Firefox). On iOs the problem doesn't present.